# Shouldn't the answer to this question be not given?

Tags: british-english, logic, ielts

Here is a link to the full passage:
https://ieltsfever.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/ieltsfever-general-reading-practice-test-3-pdf.pdf

There's a question in the IELTS reading section. Here is the quote from the passage:

> “If you plan on travelling around London to do some sight-seeing and visit some of London's best attractions, why not get a London Pass and save even more money.”

The question is:

> The cheapest option to travel around London, including sight-seeing, is using a London Pass. [*true*, *false*, or *not given*]

The model answer written on websites is: true.

Shouldn’t the answer to Q7 be *not given*?
Because there is no detailed comparison and the question says “the cheapest”.

Comment: You're correct. The addressee is sposta conclude that from "and save more money", but that's not an actionable statement, especially in tourist advertising. It may be the cheapest, but this doesn't say so, unless you believe it for them.

Comment: Even if the answer here was in fact a matter of opinion, because of the context this is a perfectly useful and helpful outcome to establish. It is not, however a matter of opinion at all.

Comment: 'Save even more money' mentions a comparison I believe needs spelling out. Can saving schemes be dovetailed ('wait 1 day until you're 65), in which case 'The cheapest option to travel around London, including sight-seeing, is using a London Pass. ' should be 'The cheapest option to travel around London, including sight-seeing, involves using a London Pass. ' The question is poor.

Comment: If you look at the whole passage rather than just the excerpts given, it lists a number of ways of paying for travel and saving money before saying "why not get a London Pass and save even more money." It's reasonable to assume that "even more money" means more than all the other ways listed. Hypothetically, it might be possible that a tourist document would entirely fail to mention the cheapest way of traveling while listing all the other ways, but that seems an unlikely assumption (based on [Grice's maxims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle), etc).

Comment: @StuartF, that would be a reasonable interpretation of the passage in a real-life situation, but some tests of this kind call for a strict, 'legalistic', approach, that ignores such considerations of pragmatics, and penalise the candidates for making the assumptions that would be reasonable in other settings. The OP is understandably confused as to what approach is expected in this case.

Comment: @StuartF Yes, what jsw29 says. One would fail these types of question if one relied on pragmatics. If it's only implied, it's 'not given'. [In theory, because IELTS seem to be quite bad at this themselves, there are always lots of disputed questions].